# Route with custom model binding doesn't work

Tags: laravel, routes, model, binding, laravel-9

I am trying to get the my route "stringified" within my File model:

```php
route('public-file', ['file' => $this]);
```

With more context:

```php
public function getPublicUrl(): ?string
{
    if ($this->isNotPublic()) {
        return null;
    }

    return route('public-file', ['file' => $this]);
}
```

My route:

```php
Route::get('/public/files/{file:public_access_token}', \App\Http\Controllers\PublicFileController::class)->name('public-file');
```

What I am expecting:

```
http://myhost.com/public/files/<token>
```

The error I am getting:

```
Missing required parameter for [Route: public-file] [URI: public/files/{file}] [Missing parameter: file].
```

What I've tried:

- `route('public-file', ['file' => $this])`
- `route('public-file', $this)`
- `route('public-file', $this->public_access_token)`

A route is successfully generated with:

```php
route('public-file', $this->id);
```

But the route is obviously invalid, as it's waiting for a public_access_token and not an ID.

Any idea ?  Thx !

ps: App running on Laravel 9.17, PHP8.1

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `PublicFileController` as well?

Comment: @OstapBrehin It's an invokable Controller, in which the `__invoke` method does basically nothing for now. 

Comment: Yes, but does it have the $file property, like this: `__invoke(File $file)` ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it @OstapBrehin The method signature is `__invoke(File $file)`.

Comment: Does cleaning route cache help? (via `php artisan route:clear` command)

Comment: @OstapBrehin Damn, that was it.. Clearly need more experience with the framework  Thx for your help !